# Как запушить commit? gitPython

Tags: python, git, git-push

использую библиотеку gitpython. Почитал документацию и до конца не разобрался как работает push. у меня уже есть commit, ветка master, имя удаленного репозитория test(уже создан, т.е мне новый не нужен), программа выглядит так(скорее всего где-то допущена ошибка):

```
from git import Repo

repo = Repo('C:\\Users\\practic\Desktop\\gg')
origin = repo.remote(name='test')
origin.push()
```

При запуске этой программы ничего не происходит, просто висит включенной. Напомню: у меня есть commit, нужно лишь отправить. Если кто-то разобрался как отправлять, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html вот документация на всякий случай

Comment: Делал когда-то такое давно... Попробуйте `repo.remotes.origin.push()`. Примеры: [1](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/gitpython_examples/append_to_remote_repo.py#L46), [2](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/gitpython_examples/cycle_commit.py#L77)

Comment: видимо устарела информация, потому что пишет что параметра origin нет(repo.remotes.origin), но все равно спасибо за помощь

Comment: Не, это вряд ли. У вашего репозитория есть ссылки на внешние репозитории? Если вы репозиторий создали через `git clone`, то `origin` должен быть. Попробуйте в консоли, в папке проекта, сделать `git remote -v show` и если в списке `origin` нет, то вручную добавить `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git` (инфу взял из этого вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184433/). А если через код делать, то в https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html поищите строку `create_remote(`

Comment: я пока выяснил, что проблема заключается не в самой отправке, а в том, что гит просит логин и пароль от аккаунта

Comment: а вот как добавить эти параметры не нашел

Comment: Это не гит просит, ему нет дела до паролей. Скорее всего, ты пушишь на гитхаб через https; либо измени remote на ssh, либо используй credential helper для запоминания пароля (но один раз как минимум его придется ввести вручную, чтобы сохранить).